# Populating TreeView with XmlDataSource without saved file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, treeview

I have a .cs file that builds an xml document and stores it in a variable.

I want to "inject" it into my `<asp:XmlDataSource>` so that I do not have to save each xml file (it is different every load). How could I go about this?

In my codebehind cs file, I have:

`XmlDocument x = blahblah`

`XmlDataSource MySource = new XmlDataSource();`

`MySource.Data = x.InnerXml`

On my aspx file I have in a form tag:

`<asp:XmlDataSource ID="MySource" runat="server" >`
`</asp:XmlDataSource>`
`<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" DataSourceId="MySource" runat="server" />`

Yet when I run this I get the easy: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: "this obviously doesn't work" - No, not obvious at all... Need more detail about why it doesn't work or what error you get.

Answer (score 2):

If the `MySource` ID of the XmlDataSource is not being recognized, your problem lies elsewhere. In normal conditions, any `runat="server"` controls you declare in the ASPX file should be accessible in the code-behind file.

You should check if the ASPX is properly mapped to the code-behind file (`@Page` declaration).

Additionally, you can directly assign the string XML into the `XmlDataSource.Data` property without the use of the intermediate variable, because it accepts a string as input.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might have just been missing a call to XmlDataSource's DataBind() method.

`MySource.DataBind();`